# Calculate initial velocity based on displacement, time and constant acceleration.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, physics

"A car has a constant speed along a road. It goes down a hill at a constant acceleration. 50s after it goes down the hill the speed is doubled and 50s later it reaches the end of the 200m hill and is back at a constant speed. Find out the initial velocity and acceleration."

At first I made relevant graphs to see if I could find some useful information from that but no luck. Then I tried to use the "[suvat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion)" equations but we haven't learned them in class so I'm not allowed to use them, which is why I'm stuck as to how to solve this basic problem.

Comment: So, what equations _are_ you allowed to use? The two facts translate into a fairly straightforward system of two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: @amd what would the system of equations be? I was trying something with integrals.

Comment: The first one is something like $v+50a=2v$, where $v$ is the initial velocity and $a$ the acceleration. The second would use the total travel time and distance to relate $a$ and $v$. If need be, you can derive that one by integrating velocity w.r. time.

Answer (score 1):

Using what @amd said,

The first equation is $v+50a=2v$, because it has constant acceleration of $a$ m/s$^2$.

Therefore, by the end of the hill, it has speed $2v+50a=3v$.

Now, knowing that in $100$ seconds, starting at an initial velocity of $v$, and ending at a velocity of $3v$, the car traveled $200m$.

Therefore, the average speed of the car was $2v$, which is $2$ m/s.

So that means that the initial velocity is $1$ m/s.

In addition, since the car took $50$ seconds to accelerate from $1$ m/s to $2$ m/s, the acceleration is $0.02$ m/s$^2$.